# Are there any easier ways to update a site than following the official instructions?

Tags: 7, updating

For tech people (like sys admins) the are the official instructions about [How to update Drupal Core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/updating-your-drupal-site/how-to-update-drupal-core) for how to update a site. But what if the user is inexperienced and just wants to maintain the site by installing security updates?

I can follow these steps myself but if I'm not available it's important that anyone (in the organization I'm volunteering for) can do it.

So, are there any easier ways to update a Drupal 7 site than following the official instructions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! _Easier way_ is rather subjective. Drupal.org lists many way to update Drupal core; which one is easier for you depends from you, or from what the domain provider offers you. If you have SSH access to the site, that would make thing easier, if you know how to handle a site using a remote shell.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to let "anyone" do the updates. Whatever way you choose, it involves someone logging into the server, and uploading files there. Whether it's from Git or rsync or just plain FTP, I wouldn't trust a non-techy person to correctly navigate the server structure and copy the files to the correct place, and not mess anything up. Even if you choose to go with Drush, this requires at least a minimal knowledge of using the terminal and navigating through the file system through command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ssh in your server install drush (drupal shell) http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

This will only need to be done once and and then it will be easy to apply drupal core updates from the command line

```
drush up drupal
```

or any other module updates

```
drush up views
```

But I would recommend applying ALL security patches at once (core and modules security updates) using

```
drush upc --security-only
```

all the above commands will do all the necessary actions as described in the instructions that you linked above and in case of a bad update the updates are reversed with error messages displayed.

To learn drush read https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drush/ but the installation instructions might be a little outdated. You can also learn more drush commands at drushcommands.com